# What is the benfit of asynchonous communication over synchornonus communication in microservice communication?

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices

All of the tutorials suggest, that we should use async communication using something like kafka over direct sync http based communication, when it comes to communication between micro-services.

Can somebody explain why, and how will async communication happen using kafka?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "why, and how"? Did you try it? The producer and consumer are completely decoupled. Yes, the producer has a callback, but 1) the broker is dumb 2) the response isn't the data that's being produced, or acknowledgement a consumer read the data

Answer (score 2):

The question is very broad. I would argue that the main aim of using async communication is to separate domain boundaries, but there are other benefits of doing this: Partition failures and the ability to support spikes without bringing down a system.

Imagine a purchase on an online shop:

- Payments needs to be processed.
- Check for fraudulent operations.
- A invoice needs to be created.
- A fulfillment order needs to be created in the warehouse.
- Purchase information has to be sent to analytics.
- Update tailored product suggestions.
- And probably a few tens more of things have to happen after an order is placed.

Some of these, the critical path, might need to happen synchronously (e.g. taken a payment) but all of the other ones can happen asyncronously. Kafka is just a message broker (check the docs or the free book [Kafka: The Definitive Guide](https://www.confluent.io/resources/kafka-the-definitive-guide/) to know how it works)

It's also possible to build a platform that is fully asynchronous (e.g. using [request-reply](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/RequestReply.html) pattern).

An incredible good explanation of using messaging and examples are in the book [Enterprise Integration Patterns](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/). It's almost 20 years since it has been published, but everything in there is still current.

Comment: Can you give me psuedo-code example of how communication will happen with message brokers, between micro-services?

Comment: @max The Kafka documentation (Java only) or Confluent Developer (other languages) site has plenty of sample code. Or plenty of other popular Kafka libraries on Github